# How to limit HTTP requests to every 2 seconds

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using Ionic 2 (Angular 2) and I have an autocomplete which makes an API request every time a word is typed. I would like to change that to every 2 seconds but I am unable to do it using `throttleTime` and `debounceTime`

service.ts

```
search(keyword): Observable<any> {
    let URL = `${this.api}/products/${keyword}`;
    return this.authService.refreshToken()
      .flatMap(() => this.authHttp.get(URL)
      .throttleTime(10000)
      .debounceTime(10000)
      .map(
        (response: Response) => {
          return response.json().products;
        },
        (error: Response) => {
          console.log(error);
        })
      .share();
}
```

searchbar.html

```
<ion-searchbar
    [showCancelButton]="true"
    [placeholder]="'Search for a Product'"
    [autocomplete] = "on"
    (input)="onSearch($event)">
</ion-searchbar>
```

component.ts

```
onSearch(event) {
    let keyword = event.target.value;
    this.searchProductsService.search(keyword)
      .subscribe(
       (products: Pinterface[]) => {
       this.products = products;
       },
       (error: Response) => {
          console.log(error);
       });
}
```

Comment: So do you now want it to send a request every 2 seconds **regardless** of if the user is typing something?

Comment: No only after the user types something (so when the http request is made in `search()`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that worked for me in case anybody needs one

.html

```
  <ion-searchbar
    [formControl]="searchControl"
    [(ngModel)]="searchTerm">
  </ion-searchbar>
```

.module.ts

```
searchTerm: string = '';
searchControl: FormControl;
constructor() {
this.searchControl = new FormControl();
}  

ionViewDidLoad() {
    // Wait 7 seconds before searching
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
       //Do whatever after 7 secs have passed
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use observables in angular2
import the react js library and then call the interval function.
if i didnt goof somthing else, then this should work:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

Observable.interval(2000)
.switchMap(() => http.get('http://yoururl.com/products/')).map((products) =>products.json())
      .subscribe(
       (products: Pinterface[]) => {
       this.products = products;
       },
       (error: Response) => {
          console.log(error);
       });
```

Comment: This wont work for me because I first make a http request to my api to refresh the token and than make the call.

Answer (score 0):

Add `debounce` property to `ion-searchbar`.

> `debounce` - input type   `number`,    How long, in milliseconds, to wait to trigger the
>   ionInput event after each keystroke. Default 250.

```
<ion-searchbar
    [showCancelButton]="true"
    [placeholder]="'Search for a Product'"
    [autocomplete] = "on"
    (input)="onSearch($event)"
    [debounce]="2000"
</ion-searchbar>
```

Comment: This isn't working for me even though its in the ionic documentation. It is still firing off requests for every word I type

Comment: Then you are doing​something wrong. Try removing all input except input and debounce. In onSeach function just console log the value. Put an ngmodel and pass in the function

Comment: Nope it doesn't work and I copied and pasted it exactly